# Как упаковать страницу JavaFx приложения в модуль?

Tags: javafx

Пусть страница конкретного приложения разрабатывается отдельно (например: структура модуля бла-бла-бла.form.login -> бла-бла-бла.form.login.Controller + бла-бла-бла.form.login.Model + бла-бла-бла.form.login.View ). Потом она может быть подключена к приложения в виде jar? Подобно тому, как в шарпе, при использовании призмы, я могу страницы приложения паковать в отдельные dll? Есть ли такая возможность в javaFx?